# How to group, calculate the number of certain columns and make averages with others pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data set:

```
[{'session_id': 'fc4867a5-cff2-4210-9ddf-9e5db35187ec', 'filters': {'color': 'red'}, 'duration': 25, 'attribute-occasion': 'Casual', 'attribute-ideal for': 'Women', 'attribute-heel height': '0 inch', 'product': 'V4STYLES Loafers', 'price': 1049}, {'session_id': 'fc4867a5-cff2-4210-9ddf-9e5db35187ec', 'filters': {'color': 'blue'}, 'duration': 25, 'attribute-occasion': 'Casual', 'attribute-ideal for': 'Women', 'attribute-heel height': '0 inch', 'product': 'V4STYLES Loafers', 'price': 1049}, {'session_id': 'fc4867a5-cff2-4210-9ddf-9e5db35187ec', 'filters': {'color': 'blue'}, 'duration': 25, 'attribute-occasion': 'Casual', 'attribute-ideal for': 'Women', 'attribute-heel height': '0 inch', 'product': 'V4STYLES Loafers', 'price': 1049}, {'session_id': 'fc4867a5-cff2-4210-9ddf-9e5db35187ec', 'filters': {'color': 'blue'}, 'duration': 25, 'attribute-occasion': 'Casual', 'attribute-ideal for': 'Women', 'attribute-heel height': '0 inch', 'product': 'V4STYLES Loafers', 'price': 1049}, {'session_id': 'fc4867a5-cff2-4210-9ddf-9e5db35187ec', 'filters': {'color': 'blue'}, 'duration': 25, 'attribute-occasion': 'Casual, Ethnic, Formal, Party', 'attribute-ideal for': 'Women', 'attribute-weight': '200 g (per single Shoe) - Weight of the product may vary depending on size.', 'product': 'dilli bazaaar Bellies, Corporate Casuals, Casuals', 'price': 349}, {'session_id': 'fc4867a5-cff2-4210-9ddf-9e5db35187ec', 'filters': {'color': 'blue'}, 'duration': 25, 'attribute-ideal for': "Women's", 'attribute-occasion': 'Casual, Party', 'attribute-pattern': 'Self Design', 'product': "F&S Casual, Party Short Sleeve Self Design Women's Top", 'price': 421}, {'session_id': 'fc4867a5-cff2-4210-9ddf-9e5db35187ec', 'filters': {'color': 'blue'}, 'duration': 25, 'attribute-ideal for': "Women's", 'attribute-occasion': 'Casual, Party', 'attribute-pattern': 'Self Design', 'product': "F&S Casual, Party Short Sleeve Self Design Women's Top", 'price': 421}, {'session_id': 'fc4867a5-cff2-4210-9ddf-9e5db35187ec', 'filters': {'color': 'green'}, 'duration': 25, 'attribute-base material': 'Brass', 'attribute-brand': 'Vendee Fashion', 'attribute-model number': 'VD8636', 'product': 'Vendee Fashion Brass Jewel Set', 'price': 829}, {'session_id': 'fc4867a5-cff2-4210-9ddf-9e5db35187ec', 'filters': {'color': 'green'}, 'duration': 25, 'attribute-base material': 'Brass', 'attribute-brand': 'Vendee Fashion', 'attribute-model number': 'VD8636', 'product': 'Vendee Fashion Brass Jewel Set', 'price': 829}, {'session_id': 'fc4867a5-cff2-4210-9ddf-9e5db35187ec', 'filters': {'color': 'green'}, 'duration': 25, 'attribute-base material': 'Brass', 'attribute-brand': 'Vendee Fashion', 'attribute-model number': 'VD8636', 'product': 'Vendee Fashion Brass Jewel Set', 'price': 829}, {'session_id': 'fc4867a5-cff2-4210-9ddf-9e5db35187ec', 'filters': {'color': 'green'}, 'duration': 25, 'attribute-base material': 'Brass', 'attribute-brand': 'Vendee Fashion', 'attribute-model number': 'VD8636', 'product': 'Vendee Fashion Brass Jewel Set', 'price': 829}, {'session_id': 'fc4867a5-cff2-4210-9ddf-9e5db35187ec', 'filters': {'color': 'green'}, 'duration': 25, 'attribute-occasion': 'Casual', 'attribute-ideal for': 'Women', 'attribute-tip shape': 'Round', 'product': 'Willy Winkies Black Boots', 'price': 999}, {'session_id': 'fc4867a5-cff2-4210-9ddf-9e5db35187ec', 'filters': {'color': 'green'}, 'duration': 25, 'attribute-occasion': 'Casual', 'attribute-ideal for': 'Women', 'attribute-tip shape': 'Round', 'product': 'Willy Winkies Black Boots', 'price': 999}, {'session_id': 'fc4867a5-cff2-4210-9ddf-9e5db35187ec', 'filters': {'color': 'green'}, 'duration': 25, 'attribute-occasion': 'Casual', 'attribute-ideal for': 'Women', 'attribute-tip shape': 'Round', 'product': 'Willy Winkies Black Boots', 'price': 999}, {'session_id': 'fc4867a5-cff2-4210-9ddf-9e5db35187ec', 'filters': {'color': 'green'}, 'duration': 25, 'attribute-ideal for': 'Women', 'attribute-occasion': 'Casual', 'attribute-weight': '500.00000000 g (per single Shoe) - Weight of the product may vary depending on size.', 'product': 'CatBird Boots', 'price': 999}, {'session_id': 'fc4867a5-cff2-4210-9ddf-9e5db35187ec', 'filters': {'color': 'green'}, 'duration': 25, 'attribute-ideal for': 'Women', 'attribute-occasion': 'Casual', 'attribute-weight': '500.00000000 g (per single Shoe) - Weight of the product may vary depending on size.', 'product': 'CatBird Boots', 'price': 999}, {'session_id': 'fc4867a5-cff2-4210-9ddf-9e5db35187ec', 'filters': {'color': 'green'}, 'duration': 25, 'attribute-ideal for': 'Women', 'attribute-occasion': 'Casual', 'attribute-weight': '500.00000000 g (per single Shoe) - Weight of the product may vary depending on size.', 'product': 'CatBird Boots', 'price': 999}, {'session_id': 'fc4867a5-cff2-4210-9ddf-9e5db35187ec', 'filters': {'color': 'green'}, 'duration': 15, 'attribute-pattern': 'Printed', 'attribute-occasion': 'Party', 'attribute-ideal for': "Men's", 'product': "Van Heusen Men's Printed Party Shirt", 'price': 1469}, {'session_id': 'fc4867a5-cff2-4210-9ddf-9e5db35187ec', 'filters': {'color': 'green'}, 'duration': 15, 'attribute-pattern': 'Printed', 'attribute-occasion': 'Party', 'attribute-ideal for': "Men's", 'product': "Van Heusen Men's Printed Party Shirt", 'price': 1469}, {'session_id': 'fc4867a5-cff2-4210-9ddf-9e5db35187ec', 'filters': {'color': 'green'}, 'duration': 15, 'attribute-pattern': 'Printed', 'attribute-occasion': 'Party', 'attribute-ideal for': "Men's", 'product': "Van Heusen Men's Printed Party Shirt", 'price': 1469}, {'session_id': 'fc4867a5-cff2-4210-9ddf-9e5db35187ec', 'filters': {'color': 'green'}, 'duration': 15, 'attribute-pattern': 'Printed', 'attribute-occasion': 'Party', 'attribute-ideal for': "Men's", 'product': "Van Heusen Men's Printed Party Shirt", 'price': 1469}, {'session_id': 'fc4867a5-cff2-4210-9ddf-9e5db35187ec', 'filters': {'color': 'green'}, 'duration': 15, 'attribute-pattern': 'Printed', 'attribute-occasion': 'Party', 'attribute-ideal for': "Men's", 'product': "Van Heusen Men's Printed Party Shirt", 'price': 1469}, {'session_id': 'fc4867a5-cff2-4210-9ddf-9e5db35187ec', 'filters': {'color': 'green'}, 'duration': 15, 'attribute-pattern': 'Printed', 'attribute-occasion': 'Party', 'attribute-ideal for': "Men's", 'product': "Van Heusen Men's Printed Party Shirt", 'price': 1469}]
```

I would like to make some bigger statistics in the sense that there will be more session_ids and more actions. At first the data frame the data appears correctly, but my question is the following:

Certain columns such as filters and attributes I want to calculate by values, it's ok if I use groupby + count

```
data = pandas.json_normalize(segmented_data)

        data('session_id').count()
```

But how could I, for example, make an average for the price and in the sense that I want a range made from that price? Is there a way to have a gender output?

```
session_id,filters.colors
fc4867a5-cff2-4210-9ddf-9e5db35187ec, red: 23, duration: average, price: average, attributes..
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: As I said above, the filter columns + attributes counted with their values ​​and for the price I want a range (average)

Comment: @KoulJak do you mean you want an interval between quantiles somewhere in the middle for each group (`session_id` in your case)? Or do you want to classify if a group's mean would fall in the interval calculated from the whole dataset?

Comment: Average of a group in the middle for each session_id